# Can't get a element by id with selenium webdriver

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver

I have a code like this.

```
require "selenium-webdriver"
d = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
d.navigate.to "http://finance.yahoo.com/stock-center/"

d.find_element(:id, "yfs_184_^oex")
```

But this code fails with `NoSuchElementError`.

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchElementError: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"yfs_184_^gsptse"}
```

I checked existence of `yfs_184_^oex` with element inspector.

Why I can't find the element by id?

Comment: This id is being created on page load time.. So you need to use other  trick. If you do view page source, you wouldn't get the id.

Comment: That seems like a dynamic ID to me.

Comment: Is there way to access dynamic ID with selenium?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are trying to find the element:

```
<span class="l84" id="yfs_l84_^oex">825.68</span>
```

The problem with the locator is that there is a typo in the id. It is "l84" - notice that it is a letter "l" not the number "1" (as in the attempted code).

```
d.find_element(:id, "yfs_l84_^oex")
```

With this change, the script will now work:

```
require "selenium-webdriver"

d = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
d.navigate.to "http://finance.yahoo.com/stock-center/"

e = d.find_element(:id, "yfs_l84_^oex")
e.text
#=> "825.68"
```